# Changing the domain of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am studying how we use polar substitution to solve double integrals. However, I am struggling with finding the correct limits of the transformed integrals to obtain a suitable solution. eg:

[image: question]

Why do we integrate between 0 and 1, then 0 and $2*\pi$?

Thanks

Comment: You need to chose your new limits so that you still reach every point in the area you're integrating over exactly once (you can relax that a bit - you may leave out a few points, and hit others more than once, so long as the sets of such points has measure zero). In the case of polar coordinates and the unit disc, that means integrating over all angles $0$ to $2\pi$, and all distances from the origin from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the unit circle (radius $1$). So $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ describes the unit disk (the circle and its interior).

To obtain the area of the unit disk, using polar coordinates,  $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \leq 1 \implies 0\leq r \leq 1$, (the points in the unit disk are of distance $d$ which ranges from $0$ to $1$ units from the origin),  and $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ (one full revolution needed to reach every point).